# DiscordJS message edits "unediting"

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I am making a discord currency bot with slash commands, but when I use `interaction.editReply()`, the edit occasionally flashes up and then "unedits". It shows the edited message for a frame and then it reverts. Does anyone know why this is and how I can fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind it wasn't working because I was using the wrong function. Using `i.update({})` fixed my problem.